# Any compliant way to connect a USB C dongle to a computer with legacy (USB A) ports only?

Tags: usb

The simplest solution would be to use an adapter with USB A male on one end and USB C female on the other. These are readily available, and would even work fine for the purpose, but are unfortunately against USB spec. I've done a lot of reading on this and understand why now (it makes it possible to connect it to another C to legacy adapter and lose the assurance that only one end believes it's the host, so USB-IF prevent this by only certifying C to legacy adapters where the C end is male).

But for someone who just wants to plug in a USB-C dongle to a USB 3 type A port it seems the non-spec way is the only real option, short of buying a new USB-C host (e.g., in the form of a PCIe card, or hub - if even that is to spec).

Is that true? If so, it seems dongles with a non-removable male USB C connection are fairly limited in use at least in a world where "legacy" type A sockets are still common.